# How to create Custom Menu in magento with active and deactive class for category?

Tags: magento

I need a custom categories menu in magento. and i want a active class on active category. when i click on category then that category should be add active class.

Comment: I need suggestion not silent down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. we can identify current category by category **getUrlKey**.

```
<?php
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ;
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCategoryId);
$childIds = explode(',',$rootCategory->getChildren());  ?>


  <div class="row">
  <?php if (count($childIds) > 0): ?>
    <ul> 
       <?php foreach($childIds as $_category):
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category);  ?>
            <?php if ($_category->getIncludeInMenu()) { ?>
            <?php $allsubchild = explode(',',$_category->getChildren());?>

          <?php  foreach($allsubchild as $_sub): ?>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
           <li class="<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_category->getUrlKey()) !== false){ echo "active";} ?>">
           <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a> 
               <?php  }  ?> 
      <ul>
            <?php $ss = 0; foreach($allsubchild as $_sub):
                $_subcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_sub); 
                ?>
                <?php if ($_subcategory->getIncludeInMenu()) { ?>  
                <?php 
                $uri = $_category->getUrlKey();
                $uri .= "/"; 
                $uri .= $_subcategory->getUrlKey(); // echo $uri; ?>

                <li class="<?php if($_subcategory->getChildrenCount()) {  echo "has-dropdown1"; }?> <?php  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uri) !== false){ echo "active";} ?>"> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $_subcategory->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php  echo $_subcategory->getName();  ?>"><?php  echo $_subcategory->getName();  ?></a>
                    <?php $suren = explode(',',$_subcategory->getChildren());?>

                    <ul> 
                    <?php   
                    foreach($suren as $suren1){
                    $suren11 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($suren1);
                     $_suren1id = $suren11->getId();
                      $internet_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_suren1id)->getProductCount();  
                      if ($internet_count > 0) {  
                     if ($suren11->getIncludeInMenu()) { ?>  
                     <?php 
                $uri1 = $uri; 
                $uri1 .= "/"; 
                $uri1 .= $suren11->getUrlKey();  // echo $uri1; ?>  

                        <li> 
                            <a class="<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $uri1) !== false){ echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $suren11->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php  echo $suren11->getName();  ?>"><?php  echo $suren11->getName();  ?></a> 
                        </li>

                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php } ?>  
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php }?>

           <?php $ss++; endforeach; ?> 
           </ul>
      </li> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

(i) First of all create your custom category from admin panel
(ii)Then pass the category id in getCategories() function in code

Try this code,it works for me.I hope this work for you.

```html
<?php
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);
?>
<div class="menusecond">
<ul id="second menu">
<?php 
foreach ($children as $category) { ?>
    <li class="mymenu">
 
 <?php $catId = $category->getId(); ?>
 <?php $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); ?> 
 <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl(); ?>">
 <?php echo $cat->getName(); ?>
 </a>
 </li>
 
 
<?php
     
}

?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not find Active or deactivate class.

Answer (score 1):

Goto app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html and open topmenu.phtml file. find this code `<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>`

this code will output you the categories in the form of top menu if you don't use any categories hide this code or else paste this code before or after this code.

`<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>your_page_uri">your_page_name</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>your_page_uri">your_page_name</a></li>
</ul>`